# Where can I download ExpressionEngine Core?

Tags: codeigniter, expressionengine

Downloading the core version used to be on the homepage. I did a google search and can't find any download link. Have they discontinued the core version of EE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes the core version has been discontinued. Sadly the 2.x range is all paid.

Comment: It's really a shame they don't offer a time-limited Zend encoded version for developers to learn on, as they did for the 2.0 beta. It makes adopting EE a riskier wager with a tight budget.

Comment: +1 for that. A trial version would be brilliant.

Comment: Worth noting that this is no longer the case, and Core has indeed returned to the ExpressionEngine offering table. http://ellislab.com/blog/entry/core-is-back

Comment: currently (July 2016) the ellislab website only offers Core for EE3, but if you want to use Core for EE2 (I'm evaluating it and the add-ons I need are not yet ported to EE3) then email their sales team and ask.